# How can i install google chrome on windows machine in build pipeline [Azure Devops]

Tags: powershell, google-chrome, azure-devops, command-line, virtual-machine

I tried using Powershell command however UAC pop up appears and i am unable to confirm the pop-up using Powershell or CMD

```
$LocalTempDir = $env:TEMP; $ChromeInstaller = "ChromeInstaller.exe"; (new-object    System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://dl.google.com/chrome/install/375.126/chrome_installer.exe', "$LocalTempDir\$ChromeInstaller"); & "$LocalTempDir\$ChromeInstaller" /silent /install; $Process2Monitor =  "ChromeInstaller"; Do { $ProcessesFound = Get-Process | ?{$Process2Monitor -contains $_.Name} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name; If ($ProcessesFound) { "Still running: $($ProcessesFound -join ', ')" | Write-Host; Start-Sleep -Seconds 2 } else { rm "$LocalTempDir\$ChromeInstaller" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Verbose } } Until (!$ProcessesFound)
```

Tried using Chocolatey getting an below error
[image]

command used - echo Y | choco install googlechrome

I am using windows machine to install the chrome

I am open with any option to install chrome.

**Note: - I am unable to run the powershell or cmd in administrator mode**

I am runnig this task in virtual machine scale set so i cant use powershell remote target machine task as well

Answer (score -1):

Please have a look at [Desired State Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/overview?view=dsc-1.1).

[Desired State Configuration Overview for Engineers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/overview/dscforengineers?view=dsc-1.1)

Here's a sample how 7Zip will be installed:
[Installing software with PowerShell DSC](https://4sysops.com/archives/installing-software-with-powershell-dsc/)

```
Configuration Install7Zip
{
     Node $env:ComputerName
     {
         Package <em>Install7Zip</em>
         {
             Ensure = 'Present'
             Name = '7-Zip 15.14 (x64 edition)'
             Path = 'C:\7z1514-x64.msi'
             ProductId = '23170F69-40C1-2702-1514-000001000000'
         }
     }
```

CI/CD can be done with a pipeline:
[Building a Continuous Integration and Continuous Deployment pipeline with DSC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/dsc-cicd?view=azure-devops)

Also Azure Automation can be used:
[Get started with Azure Automation State Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-dsc-getting-started?view=dsc-1.1)